# Better pattern than passing NSDictionaries as parameters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, model-view-controller, design-patterns

As our codebase matures I'm starting to not like the pattern of passing dictionaries as a way to package up information for message passing or, worse yet, function arguments.  It necessitates the sending and receiving function both having an undocumented API of string literals.

```
..in some function..
NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         thisObject, @"thisKey",
                         thatObject, @"thatKey",
                         nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"MY_NOTIFICATION" object:nil userInfo:info];
....
```

and then in `someClass`'s listener

```
- (void)someClassListener:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];

    ThisObject *ob1 = [info objectForKey:@"thisKey"];
    ThatObject *ob2 = [info objectForKey:@"thatKey"];
}
```

You have to remember that `thisKey` and `thatKey` are the keys of type `ThisObject` and `ThatObject` for that notification, sure you could create some constants somewhere for those keys but that doesn't really solve the problem.

And lets say you have a function that needs 15 arguments, you're not going to make a function with 15 parameters, it'd be much easier (though less readable) to just pass a dictionary but now you have the same problem as above.

I played with creating stubbed out 'Message Classes' in those class' header files (ie two interfaces in one header) and the Message Class was just a list of objects that you define and send to the method which creates a stronger contract but this feels Wrong.

It'd be great if I could do something like `typeDef` a parameter object in the header but that doesn't support `NSObject`'s only things like `int` or `float` etc.

**Essentially I'm trying to create a stronger contract between the message sender and message receiver, be that functions or notifications.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define constants for the keys. As an example, see the docs for `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` for an example. There is a link to all of the keys that can be used to get info about the notification.

A better approach would be to encapsulate your data into a class instead of a dictionary. Create a simple class with properties. This will be much more self documenting than a dictionary. You can see the property names and the property types in the .h file.

If you find you have methods needing 15 arguments, you need to step back and encapsulate those arguments into an appropriate class. Perhaps the method properly reduces to a couple of arguments and a class or something similar.

Comment: I mention constants for keys as not being a good solution because you still have to go lookup what the key is and its not creating a strong contract for what the value (object) will be, more like a suggestion.  Encapsulating the data into a class was a direction I was investigating but it seems cumbersome to create a class for every message I want to pass, be it 2 arguments are 10, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @Shizam, If those messages would be put into different dictionaries, then you would probably need more than one class. But, if you're talking about messages that sometimes pass two keys from a dictionary, and sometimes 10, then that would still just be one class object.

Comment: @rdelmar What I ment is throughout our program we probably have 10-15 unique notifications, each of those notifications would need its own class to define it's properties for the message etc.

Comment: Looks like the best way to do this is indeed to use 'Message Classes'.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a **parameter object**, a small object that encapsulates a bunch of fields for convenient communication with some other class.  Internally, the parameter object might hold a dictionary, or simply a set of designated fields.

Give the parameter object a simple API that lets both classes set and get the specific fields you use -- setThisKey: and getThisKey.  That, in essence, documents the API between the methods and classes.

Next, look for opportunities to move functionality into the parameter object.  For example, if you have something like this:

```
 param.fieldSize=[self.data size];
 param.fieldColor=[self.data color];
 param.flavor=[self.data lookUpTheRecipe]
```

You could encapsulate all this with

```
 [param withField: self.data];
```

With work, you can often make the parameter object do lots of useful work; this can break up long methods and help big classes shed excess responsibilities.

Comment: I mention this as a solution I was looking at, the problem I see is having to create a parameter object for every message, seems cumbersome.  Also it seems like the spot to put that object is in the header of the class that 'owns' the message such that you have two interfaces in one header which seems to be frowned on.

Comment: You can often share one parameter object amongst several related methods.

Comment: I see no objection to adding interfaces to helper objects to a class's header. But your goal with a parameter object is to add lots of useful behavior to that object, not merely to wrap some data. So, eventually,  the parameter object may deserve its own place in the world. Classes like NSURL get started this way.

Answer (score 0):

At first, having 15 arguments is not good and in such case you should think about not doing such callbacks or trying to reduce the number.

---

What about using the sender of notification? For example your object `Task` finished and sends notification. The receiver uses the sender to access `sender.result`, `sender.error`, `sender.anything`.

---

If you want stronger contact between those objects (sender / receiver) maybe you should use some other way of communication instead of `NSNotifications`.

Some alternatives:

- delegate (or some other kind of direct method call)
- blocks
- target+action

All of them can be used as to-many callbacks by storing them in an array and they don't use `NSDictionaries` for value passing.

Comment: We use delegates and blocks as well, I was just using NSNotifications as an example where its easy to see the problem.  I still have this problem with blocks etc but I'm starting to think that creating parameter objects to contain the parameters is pretty much the only way to do it.